# Degree of freedom with mixed model using nlme package?

Tags: r, mixed-model, degrees-of-freedom

I am conducting a mixed model, but do not well understand how `df` is calculated, can someone help me to clarify it? I have been searching very hard on the internet but could not find the right answer.

The data in fact contains `Animal` as random effect, `Breed` and `DFC` (day from calving) and `squared_DFC` as fixed effect, and `Red` My as the response variable.
The mixed model is:

```
model <- lme(Red_MY ~ DFC + DFC*Breed, random=~1|Animal, 
             data= my_data)
```

The output:

```
Red_BW ~ DFC + DFC * Breed + Squared_DFC
    
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: na.omit(my_data) 
       AIC     BIC    logLik
  24045.02 24086.5 -12015.51

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Cow_code
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    7.700506 17.80507

Fixed effects: Red_BW ~ DFC + DFC * Breed + Squared_DFC 
                       Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)        2.3266511 2.4810473 2688  0.937770  0.3484
Centred_DFC       -0.0232875 0.0080565 2688 -2.890523  0.0039
Breed             -1.3165288 1.1309444   80 -1.164097  0.2478
Squared_DFC       -0.0003436 0.0000345 2688 -9.957905  0.0000
Centred_DFC:Breed -0.0115884 0.0037693 2688 -3.074444  0.0021
 Correlation: 
                  (Intr) DFC Breed  Sq_DFC
Centred_DFC        0.061                     
Breed             -0.912 -0.060              
Squared_DFC       -0.183  0.002  0.009       
Centred_DFC:Breed -0.063 -0.924  0.067  0.026

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
         Min           Q1          Med           Q3          Max 
-4.649177035 -0.562679661 -0.004077324  0.521083911  8.448741285 

Number of Observations: 2773
Number of Groups: 82
```

Comment: It's in Pinheiro and Bates (2000): see http://tinyurl.com/ntygq3 for the relevant page on Google Books.

Answer (score 0):

I follow @BenBolker's advice and look up the formula in (Pinheiro and Bates, 2000); it's on page 91.
$$
\operatorname{DF}_i = m_i - \left(m_{i-1} + p_i\right)
$$
where $m_i$ is the number of groups on level $i$ (with $m_0 = 1$ when the fixed effects include an intercept and $m_0 = 0$ otherwise), and $p_i$ is the number of (effective) parameters at level $i$.

Let's determine the $m_i$s and $p_i$s for the OP's model. This linear mixed model has two levels, one for the animals and one for the observations. Therefore:

```r
m_0 <- 1    # the model has an intercept term
m_1 <- 82   # number of groups (animals)
m_2 <- 2773 # number of observations
```

Moreover, there is one group-level predictor Breed (each animal is of a specific breed) and three individual-level predictors (DFC, DFC<sup>2</sup> and the interaction between DFC and Breed).

```r
p_1 <- 1 # one degree for Breed
p_2 <- 3 # one degree each for Centered_DFC, Squared_DFC, Centred_DFC:Breed
```

Note: The model treats both DFC (days from calving) and Breed as numeric. This makes sense for DFC (and its two transformations, Centered_DFC and Squared_DFC) but it won't make sense for Breed unless there are only two breeds coded as 0 and 1.

Finally, we calculate the (denominator) degrees of freedom according to the (Pinheiro and Bates, 2000) formula.

```r
denDF_1 <- m_1 - (m_0 + p_1)
denDF_2 <- m_2 - (m_1 + p_2)

denDF_1
#> [1] 80
denDF_2
#> [1] 2688
```

This matches that degrees of freedom (DF) reported in the summary table.